# Node.js Connect.bodyParser like form data parser for JSP/Servlets

Tags: html, forms, jsp, servlets, node.js

I'm looking for a very lightweight form data parser that would work in JSP or Servlets. What I basically want to do is parse something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="person[1][name]"/>
<input type="text" name="person[1][food]"/>
```

To JSON format

```
person= {
  1: {
    name: NAME,
    food: FOOD
  }
}
```

Or any equivalent Hash/Associative arrray
I'm pretty sure this is what [Connect's bodyParser](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-bodyParser.html) does, I'm not sure about other languages/frameworks. Is there anything for JSP/Servlets that performs this functionality?

EDIT:
I decided to clarify that by parse I mean parse after the submission, so parse the form's POST data.

EDIT2:
Sorry for constantly editing, but I think it's still not clear. What I basically want is a piece of software that will allow me not to play with separate POST variables, but put them all into this more robust set of associative arrays.

Comment: Here is the exact code that Connect/Node uses to do that.  It's pretty simple: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/querystring.js#L155

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this exactly what bodyParser does?

http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-bodyParser.html

If it doesn't get the key hierarchy right then I bet the connect guys would accept a patch.

Comment: I think you haven't read the question. That is exactly what bodyParser does and I acknowledge that in the question. What I wanted was something like that for JSP/Servlet pages. Anyway, I wrote my own.